# Whats wrong in this jQuery dropdown menu code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I found that simple snippet which worked perfectly for 2 dependant dropdowns but now i need to add a third dropdown that depend on the selection on the second dropdown, i tried to alter the code but it didn't work, Sorry im totally new in JS.. i just started learning php lately...

Please note that the original snippet was using value for filtering instead of id, and i altered it because i wanna use the select value in POST request.

```js
    var $select1 = $( '#select1' ),
      $select2 = $( '#select2' ),
        $select3 = $( '#select3' ), // I added that line but not sure if its correct
        
        $options_a = $select2.find( 'option' );
      $options_b = $select3.find( 'option' ); // I added that line but not sure if its correct
        
    $select1.on( 'change', function() {
     $select2.html( $options_a.filter( '[id="' + this.value + '"]' ) );
    } ).trigger( 'change' );
    
    // I added the next lines for select3 but not sure if they are correct
    $select2.on( 'change', function() {
     $select3.html( $options_b.filter( '[id="' + this.value + '"]' ) );
    } ).trigger( 'change' );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="select1" id="select1">
        <option value="" disabled selected>Select your option</option>
        <option value="1" id="1">Fruit</option>
        <option value="2" id="2">Animal</option>
        <option value="3" id="3">Bird</option>
        <option value="8" id="4">Car</option>
    </select>
    
    <select name="select2" id="select2">
        <option value="" disabled selected>Select your option</option>
        <option value="1" id="1">Banana</option>
        <option value="2" id="1">Apple</option>
        <option value="3" id="1">Orange</option>
        <option value="4" id="2">Wolf</option>
        <option value="5" id="2">Fox</option>
        <option value="6" id="2">Bear</option>
        <option value="7" id="3">Eagle</option>
        <option value="8" id="3">Hawk</option>
        <option value="9" id="4">BWM<option>
    </select>
    
    <select name="select3" id="select3">
        <option value="" disabled selected>Select your option</option>
        <option value="1" id="1">Small</option>
        <option value="2" id="2">Medium</option>
        <option value="3" id="2">Large</option>
        <option value="4" id="3">Large</option>
    
    </select>
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong. It does exactly what you are saying through your code. When you select the option in the select 2, it selects the option/s in the select 3 with the same id of the option selected in the select 2

Comment: Not really. If you select first, second and third, and after that you change first, 2 will clear, but third will stay the same. You must reset selection of child selects after each change.

Comment: @quirimmo Thanks for reply, actually the code was returning wrong results in select 3, I just discovered the solution, i need to change $select2.on  in line 13 to $select1.on ... but not sure why!!

Comment: Ok. Btw, id attributes should be unique. Use another name for the atttrib, like data-id or some.

Comment: @MerakMarey I think i solved the issue with wrong filtering on select3 by changing line 13 to $select1.on instead of $select2.on .... but i dont understand why choose a unique id and if i choosesed unique id per each option then how i will filter it... i think i cant use value attribute for filtering because i wanna send a specific data that i will store in option values as POST request

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. A couple of things that will help you get better answers here is to be clear in what you've tried and what results you got, *i tried to alter the code but it didn't work* isn't helpful to us. What did you try and what about it didn't work? Did you get an error? Also, please don't post example code to 3rd party sites, just include your code in a "code snippet" right here in your question.

Comment: @arabtornado When I said don't use id I meant literally the word 'id'..use data-id, or option-id, but not just "id"...attribute id is a native attribute, and it should be unique by element, whatever they are, you are just trying to use it as a filter to group options.. read more here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id

Comment: @MerakMarey Thanks Merak, I edited it but not im stuck with a new issue :(
Im stuck with the filtering of the third dropdown, The filtering of the third dropdown supposed to look like this https://snag.gy/Ls6dnf.jpg

so "Comfort Cushion" have an empty select 3 and "Freilagerungssitzkissen" should have Standard and large on select 3 and "Rückenkissen" should have small and standard... i tried but could know how to assign ids to filter like this... i updated the jsfiddle link, please re-check

https://jsfiddle.net/rg2de5yj/3/

Comment: Lets go back a second and try to explain us what is the intended behavior you want.  Correct me if I'm wrong. You want that based on the selection of select#1 you filter the possible options available for select#2, and then based on selection of select#2, filter the possible options for select#3? Its that what you want?

Comment: Yes, exactly, and here show the the hierarchy of the 3 dropdowns
https://snag.gy/Ls6dnf.jpg